# Git failing with "Unable to create '<projectPath>/.git/index.lock': Permission denied" even though it should have all permissions

Tags: git, permissions

I am trying to do a git reset and am getting the following error:

```
fatal: Unable to create '<path>/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

If I do an "ls -al .git" prior to running the process, I see that there is no index.lock. If I do it again after attempting the reset, I see that it has been created. So it clearly does have permission to create the file (and in fact succeeds in creating it) but is still reporting the error.

I've deleted the lock file and run it again, but I get the same issue. I've also tried running it again without deleting the file and of course I get a similar error message saying that the file already exists.

The permissions of my .git directory are drwxrwxrwx and the permissions of the index.lock file that it creates are -rwxrwxrwx.

I am running on RHEL 6.6 with git 1.7.1

I'm not using any sort of git tools other than the git command itself (so no tortious git or an IDE with git integrated or anything like that).

The exact command I am running is

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

One possibly relevant thing to note: I created this repository on a different machine. I then put it on a CD and transferred it to another machine. Is it possible that this is somehow related to change in machine, path, OS, or git version?

The only absolute path I see via "git config --list" is "remote.origin.url" but it shouldn't need origin for that command and I wouldn't think it would create some sort of issue with the index.lock file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.

It turns out that this issue actually had nothing to do with git.

I'm still not sure about the exact details of why this wasn't working, but it turned out to be a file system and file permissions issue instead.

I hadn't realized this at the time, but the file system I was working on was actually a windows shared drive. I'm not sure what service it was using to serve the Linux filesystem, but this was clearly the issue. I moved to a Linux shared drive and now it is working just fine.

In case anyone else is interested, here are some commands I ran on the Windows drive and there outputs. You can see that it behaves pretty strangely:

```
>echo "foo" > bar
>ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    4 Oct 4 2016 bar
>cat bar > foo
>ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    4 Oct 4 2016 bar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    4 Oct 4 2016 foo
>cp foo foocpy
cp: cannot create regular file 'foocpy': Permission denied
>ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 nate unixusers 4096 Oct 4 2016 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    4 Oct 4 2016 bar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    4 Oct 4 2016 foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate unixusers    0 Oct 4 2016 foocpy
>cat foocpy
>cat foo
foo
>cat bar
bar
```

Pretty weird stuff.

Anyway, I'm not trying to ask another question here. This resolution is good enough for me and I'm only posting the above examples to demonstrate that it is weird. If anyone wants to know why the Windows drive is behaving the way it is, then they can ask their own question, but this is good enough for me.